# your program produce no output

Tags: python

I am new to the field. simple program, all I need to do is to find the smallest number.

```
number1 = input ('')
number2= input('')
number3 = input('')

number1 = input ('')
number2= input('')
number3 = input('')

if (number1<number2) and (number1<number3):
    smallest=number1
elif (number2<number1) and (number2 < number3):
    smallest=number2
else:
    smallest=number3

print(smallest)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's your question?

Comment: Hi, for some reason these code doesn't give any output

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? You input the same numbers twice... is that intentional? This program does print an output (perhaps an empty string if empty strings are entered).

Comment: We need to know the input to say what it should produce.

Comment: this is school lab, they are are using Python3.

Comment: input 7, 15, 3. so the smallest is 3, but on my screen it keeps saying either 15 to program produce no output.

Comment: Is it intended to redefine the `number1`, `number2`, and `number3` variables? Currently, it seems like the second set of `input()` statements serve no purpose.

Comment: I think I did it by accident, it should be just one set of numbers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string:

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a **string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Because of this, all checks amongst the input values won't be between integers, as you want, but strings, [leading to comparisons being based upon lexicographical ordering rather than value.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types) This can be solved by converting the inputs to integers:

```
number1 = int(input(''))
number2 = int(input(''))
number3 = int(input(''))

if (number1 < number2) and (number1 < number3):
    smallest = number1
elif (number2 < number1) and (number2 < number3):
    smallest = number2
else:
    smallest = number3

print(smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `input('')`, it takes the number from terminal (at the running time), so your code is OK, just to understand how it works, run your modified code below, some added strings can help you find your problem better.

```
number1 = input('Please insert the first number ?')
number2 = input('Please insert the second number ?')
number3 = input('Please insert the third number ?')

if (number1 < number2) and (number1 < number3):
    smallest = number1
elif (number2 < number1) and (number2 < number3):
    smallest = number2
else:
    smallest = number3

print("result is :  ", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `min()` and `max()`

```
n1,n2,n3 = 1,2,3
print("min:", min(n1,n2,n3) )
print("max:", max(n1,n2,n3))
```

***output***:

```
> min: 1
> max: 3
```

Comment: I am just a beginner at Python, the instructor doesn't want us to use min or max functions. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter "7", "15", and "3", your program compares those three values as strings, which means that it will find the one that is "smallest" *alphabetically* -- the first character is compared first, which makes "15" come first in the ordering (then "3", then "7").

To fix this, you need to convert the values to `int`s:

```
number1 = int(input())
```

You may be getting blank strings ("") in some cases because you copied and pasted the input lines, which means you're getting prompted six times and only the last three times count.

Overall the fixed version of your code would look like:

```
number1 = int(input())
number2 = int(input())
number3 = int(input())

if number1 < number2 and number1 < number3:
    smallest = number1
elif number2 < number3:
    smallest = number2
else:
    smallest = number3

print(smallest)
```

Note that you don't need to pass an empty string to `input()` (it defaults to an empty string), and you don't need the parentheses around your comparison operations (because `<` already takes precedence over `and`).

A shortened version of this code that uses `min` and a loop would be:

```
print(min(int(input()) for _ in range(3)))
```

In this line of code, the expression `int(input()) for _ in range(3)` generates three inputs (one per number in `range(3)`), and the `min` function finds the minimum value from that generator.  The nice thing about using a loop like this is that you can easily make it work for any number of inputs without having to write a bunch more `if ... < ...` checks!